# Grails 2.2.0 URLMappings: Any way to use same URL with Different Verb

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I have the following:

```
"/api/users"(controller: "user") {
   action = [GET:"list"]
}
```

Doing a call to `http://localhost:8080/platform/users` I get a list of users back.  Then I added this:

```
"/api/users"(controller: "user") {
   action = [POST:"save"]
}
```

And now I get a 404 and it is not hitting either method in UserController.  I'd like to be able to use the same URL with the verb controlling which action.  Am I doing this wrong or does Grails not support this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Grails docs: [URL Mappings](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings)

```
static mappings = {
   "/product/$id"(controller:"product") {
       action = [GET:"show", PUT:"update", DELETE:"delete", POST:"save"]
   }
}
```

For your case:

```
"/api/users"(controller: "user") {
   action = [GET:"list",POST:"save"]
}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I knew that.  Must..get..sleep.  Thanks James.

Comment: What about if the methods are in separate controllers? Or for example /users goes to one action and /users/1111 goes to another?

Comment: @Jackie than probably you have bad planned app structure. Remember  also about redirects if it's more sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

Check your userController to see if there is allowedMethods defined accordingly like this:

```
class UserController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", list: "GET"]

    def list() {
    .....
    }

    def save() {
    .....
    }
}
```